# How do I update geolocation state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a user's geolocation and update the state with the latitude and longitude. I followed [the MDN docs for the Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), but I'm getting an error that success is undefined, even though I defined it according to the docs. How can I make this code work?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { latitude: null, longitude: null };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            success => this.state.latitude =
                success.coords.latitude, this.state.longitude = success.coords.longitude
        );
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.latitude}, {this.state.longitude}</div>;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can be a bit confusing in the console because the error is not actually in regards to `success`, but rather `this` referencing `success`. You are not assigning the state correctly. You must change state using `setState`. You cannot change state by directly assigning it a new value.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { latitude: null, longitude: null };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            success => this.setState({ latitude: success.coords.latitude, longitude: success.coords.longitude })
        );
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.latitude}, {this.state.longitude}</div>;
    }
}
```

You can read more about the keyword `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It's a very important concept to understand if you are going to be working in React.js.